# VM client restart

Tags: process, thin-client, vmware-view

I am using a wyse terminal (thin client) with xpe.  I have disabled explorer in registry and replaced the shell with the vm client so at startup it looks like a windows logon but its VM view client instead.  This all works well however when I log off it just goes to a blank desktop (because there is no explorer).  Is there a way to get the vm view client to load straignt into the logon screen once the previous session logs off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a batch file as the shell:

### vm.bat

> :START
>
> {vmclient.exe} (use whatever the real filename is)
>
> goto START

That way it keeps restarting after it is terminated.

Comment: Good idea, cheers will try that out and post result

Comment: It worked well I want the batch file to run invisible. I found a w script command however how can I execute a wscript in a file so that I can point the wscript to the shell?

Comment: This is the script I want to run wscript "E:\downloads\invisible.vbs" "E:\downloads\vm.bat"

Comment: I found a way to do it.  I have this script called vm.vbs containing CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & "C:\vm.bat" & """", 0, False
it calls the vm.bat that you wrote.
:START /MIN
cd\
C:
cd program files\VMware\VMware View\Client\bin\
wswc.exe
goto START

Then I got an application called Vbs To Exe 1.1 available for free from http://3d2f.com/programs/59-436-vbs-to-exe-download.shtml.
I then created VMshell.exe using that app and now I use that as my Shell.  Thanks for you help much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked!